# How can I find a subgraph from a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

At the moment i'm studying planar graphs and it notes that a graph can only be planar if it contains a subgraph which is homeomorphic to k3,3 or k5.

I understand this; but am not sure as to how to find a subgraph of a specific graph. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A graph is planar if and only if it *does not* contain a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.

Comment: In order to show that a graph is planar it suffices to provide a planar drawing of it. But in order to show that a graph is *not* planar we have to find some forbidden substructure in it. This is an algorithmic question and there exists an algorithm which checks whether a given graph is planar or not.